# Hide Div Control on Page Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$(function () {
        $("#divLimitPrice").hide();
        $('#divLimitPrice').hide(); //even tried it with ''
    });

 <div id="divLimitPrice">Limit Price<br />
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtLimitPrice" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
 </div>
```

My understanding is that this is supposed to work..... it wants to fight me. Any way to beat it into submission? Thanks all!
- G

Comment: You've included jQuery before that JS snippet, right? Also JS needs to be in `<script>` tags (although that could have been left out for the sake of conciceness)

Comment: Here's the full script- thanks! <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#divLimitPrice').hide();
        });
        function OnSelection(me) {
            // find the selected value
            var SelectedValue = jQuery('option:selected', me).attr('value');
            // if selected value = x then...
            if (SelectedValue == "Limit")
                jQuery("#divLimitPrice").show();
            else
                jQuery("#divLimitPrice").hide();
        }
    </script>

Comment: That should be edited into your post - there's a button underneath the tags to do so

Comment: Here is your code: http://jsfiddle.net/erdemkeren/VVfA3/7/ It didn't try to fight. Seems submissively doing what it must... I don't want to say "check your jquery link" but there should be some bug hidden between your code snippets..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 <div id="divLimitPrice">Limit Price<br />
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtLimitPrice" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
 </div>
<script>
    $(function () {
            $("#divLimitPrice").hide();
        });
</script>
```

I think your problem is the JS is executing before the page loads.

Comment: LOL! No relation. `$(function ()` means "do the nested jobs after page is loaded".

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#divLimitPrice").hide();
}); @Aletz, you're right. If I put it after, it works. Isn't this supposed to work once the page is ready?^^ For some reason it doesn't want to play nice.

Comment: yes $(document).ready it's supposed to work in that way. However i used to have the same issues working with asp tags in my case using telerik, but using your script at the bottom of the page is a good practice and in most cases it works.

Answer (score 5):

It will flicker if you use JS as the script has to load first which means until it's loaded the div will remain visible on the DOM.

The easiest way to do this is to give your div a CSS class of display none like following. That way when the page is loaded it will already be hidden.

```
<div id="divLimitPrice" class="hide-div">Limit Price<br />
```

```
 hide-div { 
     display: none;
 }
```

When you need it to be shown you can use jQuery as follows:

```
$('#divLimitPrice').removeClass('hide-div')
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: ahh okay. I initially set the value hidden="hidden" on the control but during the postback on the page it would auto hide it again. Any way to make it so that when the page loads for the first time its hidden and i have to code to show it, but when they click the button, it issues a postback and then the control hides again... can't say I'm an expert with Javascript/Jquery ... sadly. So not really sure where to begin. Btw, thanks for the quick response!

Comment: If you're hiding the div using CSS then hidden="hidden" is redundant.  If the page posts back and refreshes then by default "hide-div" would once again be active on the div and it would be hidden. Does that help?

Comment: Thanks Kyle. It does help. Is there a way to detect a postback and if so, show the Div? Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#divLimitPrice").hide();
});
```

Comment: Yes, I know. I was just thinking it might be conflicting with other javascript. So just wanted to try.

Comment: That's weird, I thought this would have worked. no luck! I think @Aletz Morgan is right, that the JS is running before the page is loaded so it doesnt work. If i put the script after the Div command it works...